# AMCharts 4 Directed Tree - Find a Node and Zoom it

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to search a node in a Force Directed Tree with Amcharts 4 using JavaScript. After I found the node, I'd like to zoom the chart on the node.

I'm trying to search the node by its name in the DOM but it's not working as expected.

`chart.zoomToDataItem(itemToFind, zoom = 1.85, true);`

Unfortunatly I don't know how to find an item, and I can't find in the doc either. Does any one can help me ?

Thank you for your help,

Kind Regards